# Map single layer from list in Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I'm trying to map an isolated month of imagery reduced with a median reducer in Earth Engine. However, when I try to incorporate code from [this approach](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/279531/67264) (also tried using the `listOfImages[2]` approach in the other answer to that question) I can't map the resulting object. It's confusing because when I print the object, it shows that I have an image, but I get the error:

> Cannot add an object of type ComputedObject to the map.

I looked into [this solution](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304631/cannot-add-an-object-of-type-object-as-a-layer) to a similar error, but I don't think my code is mapping a list object, based on the fact that `print("March LS8",Mar);` returns a 3-band Image. Ultimately I want to maintain my 12-image imageCollection ("monthVis") for exporting purposes.

Reproducible code:

```
// Define (example) region of interest
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('NAME', 'Waldo'));
Map.centerObject(ROI, 9);
Map.addLayer(ROI);

//// Image manipulation
// Create clipping function so we're just dealing with the ROI
var clipper = function(image){
  return image.clip(ROI);
};

// Visualization function for median imageCollections
var vizzer = function(x){
  return x.visualize({bands: ['B4_median', 'B3_median', 'B2_median'], min: 0, max: 7000});
};

//// Load imagery
// Load a raw Landsat scene and display it.
var raw = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate("2013-01-01", "2018-12-31")
  .map(clipper);    

//// Rearrange imagery
// Based on code by Nicholas Clinton https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/258379/67264
var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function (m) {
        return raw.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .reduce(ee.Reducer.median())
                    .set('month', m);
}));

//// Look at imagery
print("monthlyAggs", byMonth);
var monthVis = byMonth.map(vizzer);
print("monthVis", monthVis);

// Map specified layer using a List.
var listOfImages = monthVis.toList(monthVis.size());
print("listOfImages", listOfImages);
var Mar = listOfImages.get(2);
print("March LS8",Mar); // Returns an image
Map.addLayer(Mar, {}, "March LS8"); // Returns an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function**get** of a list returns an object of type *Object* (or computed object). But **Map.addLayer** takes either *Collection/Feature/Image/MapId*. Since your computed object is an image, all you need to do is cast it to an image object.

```
var Mar = ee.Image(listOfImages.get(2));
```